# Call class from placeholder code (dynamic code) in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got names of several tables lets say for example
"AAA"
"CGL"
"GHS"
and so on - could be a large number of tables with totally different names.
I got a table view with a search bar set up and need information for the detail view of each row in the table view.

The thing is, in order for that I need to call classes exactly named like the tables with a prefix
so the classname I need to call is "XxAAA" in order to call methods to get data.

```
NSString *syncGroup = [XxAAA metaData].synchronizationGroup;
```

This is one example (synchronizationGroup returns a NSString) - and this should happen in a loop so it replaces the XxAAA with the correct table name + prefix.
I found out how to set a string to "Xx "+ table name thats not the problem.
But how do I dynamically call the class? I hope you know what I mean,
please help, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
[NSClassFromString(@"XxAAA") metaData].synchronizationGroup;
```